# isauthenticated() isanonymous() in spring is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am giving html and depedencies :

1.Myhtml file:

```
<li><a   href='#'>SHOOPING CART</a>
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"> 
<a  class="btn btn-primary pull-right"  th:href="@{/login}">My Account1</a>
</div> 
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
<a  class="btn  pull-right"  th:href="@{/myProfile}">My Account</a>
<a  class="btn  pull-right"  href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
</div>
```

2.I had added following dependecies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>${thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>${thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.jpenren</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>${thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My page is showing both my account buttons even though i am using isanonymous and isauntheticated options.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by adding following codes in the starting of the html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```